# Apache Redirect in htaccess to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've built an in house app that needs to start in public folder, directory structure is as follows

```
myapp/conf
myapp/tmp
myapp/doc
myapp/public
myapp/public/css
myapp/public/js
myapp/public/index.php
```

If a user installs it in webroot subdirectory, instead of making myapp/public the webroot, then the URLs would be

somehost/myapp/public/index.php

How do I redirect with /myapp/.htaccess, so that it forwards everything to /public/index.php BUT also changes the URL to include /public.

I have figured out how to redirect to public, but since i'm doing URL Rewrites in /public/, i need $_SERVER['REQUEST_URL'] to have /public/ in the path.

I'd like to prevent access to everything else (/conf and /doc etc..)

any luck?

What i tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ public [L]
</IfModule>
```

But this seems to put public before `myapp` and the url looks like this: `localhost/public/myapp/`, instead I need `localhost/myapp/public/`

In simpler terms, I want all URLS to /whatever/* to have public appended to it /whatever/public/*.

The solution needs to be independent of the domain name and 'myapp' name. They could name the root folder ('myapp') whatever but it will always have a sub dir called 'public'.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myapp/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/
RewriteRule (.*) public/index.php/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ public [L]
```

The main thing is you need to change the base to your app name. Then the rules can remain the same. The condition is needed to prevent redirect looping. But you probably won't need it if you have an .htaccess file handling requests inside /public/.

Comment: This will work only for the application myapp (and he is looking for a solution that will will for all apps)

Comment: ya, I have no control over what they will call the 'myapp' folder. It could be anything. What about another solution. Bring the contents of public and just limit access to my secret folder conf/ and /doc etc...maybe show a 503. If they make other folders, then they can access those. Would this be easier to do with htaccess?