# Define base url for laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel.  My url for my only controller is

```
http://localhost/myapp/public/users
```

In the views for the form functions, I don't want to have to do an absolute path to the post function, e.g.

```
<form method='post' action='/myapp/public/user/update-user'>
```

I want to just set the users controller as the base url path so I can say in my form

```
<form method='post' action='/update-user'>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you not do this using routes? Also, your URLs should not be /myapp/public/user/update-user, they should be without /myapp/public. Maybe your Laravel installation is configured incorrectly?

Comment: ahh maybe so.  Can you direct me how to make it configured correctly?

Comment: I'm absolutely new to the world of routes too, so I don't know how to that!  I have been looking but I can't quote figure it out.

Comment: Did you install Laravel via composer? And Routes can be difficult to grasp at first, I would suggest having a play about with them, trying to get them to work, and once you feel you can't progress any further, post a question up specifying what you need

Comment: Yes I installed it via composer.  Ok, I will do that, thanks.  Can you direct me as to what I need to edit to lose the myapp/public part from my url?

Comment: Take a look at this post -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893738/apache-redirect-in-htaccess-to-subdirectory

Answer (score 2):

Use URL::to() 
or simply use laravel form 
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'route_name'))}}

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL::to() function.Laravel supports RESTful API or RESTful routing. So it is not a good idea to use routing like this.So use like,
In ***app/routes.php***

```
// for view (GET)
Route::get('users', function(){
   View::make('users');
});

Route::post('users', function(){
  // do form validation and process here or call a function from controller
});
```

Then in your form use,

```
echo Form::open();
// form elements
echo Form::close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but it's a little complicated because laravel isn't really set up to support this.

You need to change the file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php`, replacing the function `root()` with this:

```
public function root($domain = NULL)
{
    return rtrim(($domain?:$this->getSchemeAndHttpHost()).$this->getBaseUrl(), '/');
}
```

And then in the `getRootUrl($scheme, $root = null)` method in the file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php` you need to change this line:

```
$root = $root ?: $this->request->root();
```

to this:

```
$root = $this->request->root($root);
```

That should allow laravel to automatically detect and handle subfolders correctly, so you will be able to use the standard URL methods.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to hide the /public/ part of your URL using the virtual host or the alias in your web server (apache or ...). The entry point (http://some.host/alias/ or http://some.virtual.host/) should lead directly to the public folder (i.e. /whatever/path/myapp/public/).

Second, using the routes, you can do the remaining easily. The route

```
Route::get('update_users', "UsersController@updateAction")
```

will redirect the http://whatever.host/update_users to the correct action without the need of the ugly format.