# Apache alias/rewrite to a subdirectory without redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.2, mod-alias

As an example, I am accessing project `foo` at `https://localhost/projects/foo/dev/`.

I'd like to rewrite the URL so that `https://localhost/projects/foo/` points to `projects/foo/dev/` in my DocumentRoot folder

This should **not** be an HTTP 3xx redirect. Furthermore `dev1`, `dev2`, and so on should not be accessible (unless there are directories inside of `dev` with those names but that's unlikely). Of course the rest of the path as well as query strings and fragments need to retained, for example:

```
projects/foo/dev/assets/js/jquery.min.js -> https://localhost/projects/foo/assets/js/jquery.min.js
```

This is my directory structure in my DocumentRoot folder:

- projects/

  - foo/

    - dev/
    - dev1/
    - dev2/
    - dev3/
  - bar/

    - dev/
    - dev1/
    - dev2/
  - and so on...

I've tried the answer posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893738/apache-redirect-in-htaccess-to-subdirectory) but it isn't taking effect even after restarting Apache.

I've also tried this which seems correct but is giving me HTTP 500 with some infinite redirects error in `error.log`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ src/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I only have access inside each project directory (e.g. `foo` and `bar`) and the parent directory may not be called `projects` on other machines. Therefore this needs to be done within htaccess files and not httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your `projects/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $2 !^dev/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(foo|bar)/(.*)$ $1/dev/$2 [NC,L]
```

Or for each directory in `projects/` (not only `foo`and `bar`):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $2 !^dev/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ $1/dev/$2 [L]
```